# Does $A^{-1}$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose A is similar to the matrix B given below.
$$
B=  \begin{bmatrix}
        7 & 0 & 0 \\
        a_{21} & 4 & 0 \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & -0.5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Does $A^{-1}$ exist? If so, what is det($A^{-1}$)?

Okay so I first found the det(B) = -14. This means that B does not have an inverse. I then decided to find the eigenvalues of B because since the two matrices are similar they have the same eigenvalues. And, for a square matrix the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. So, if I found the eigenvalues and their product is not zero then I know that the inverse for A does no exist. However, I am having trouble finding the eigenvalues. I first plugged it into

[$\lambda$I-B] = 0

$
 \begin{bmatrix}
        \lambda-7 & 0 & 0 \\
        a_{21} & \lambda-4 &0 \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & \lambda+ 0.5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Then I got
$2\lambda^3 -7\lambda^2 +17\lambda +28 =0$

This is where I stopped and got stuck. Can someone help?

Comment: Why doesn't $B$ have an inverse? Note that since $B$ is triangular, then its eigenvalues are the diagonal entries.

Comment: the eigenvalues of an lower triangular matrix are its diagonal entries; here they are $7, 4, -0.5$

Comment: @CameronBuie I thought that when the det(B) does not equal zero then it does not have the inverse

Comment: Other way around. It has an inverse *unless* its determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as $A$ is similar to $B$, there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}$.  As the determinant is multiplicative and $\det(M^{-1})=\det(M)^{-1}$, we have

$$\det(A)=\det(PBP^{-1})=\det(P)\det(B)\det(P)^{-1}=\det(B)$$

As $B$ is triangular $\det(A)=\det(B)=7\cdot4\cdot(-.5)=-14\neq0$, and so $A$ is invertible.  Finally

$$\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}=\frac{-1}{14}$$